# Why the area of a square is $side^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I recently stumbled upon Edwin Moise's proof of the area of a square, but there is something that is bothering me in his proof - he claims that since the inequalities $(1)$ and $(5)$ are true, then $a =\sqrt{S_a}$. but why? why $(1)$ and $(5)$ imply that there is an equality between $a$ and $\sqrt{S_a}$?

I would be grateful if you could explain his proof, especially the latter part.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: He doesn't caim 1 and 5 are true, but that they are equivalent.

Comment: I guess $\alpha$ here means 'area'.

Comment: They hold for every rational, so....

Comment: So basically, if $a$ is irrational then you can exhaust $S_a$ with rational squares $S_{p/q}$. And I guess the point of doing this is that with $S_{p/q}$ you can dilate everything by $q$ and then identify the dilated square with $p^2$ 1x1 squares, and then go back and divide by $q^2$ to cancel the effect of the dilation.

Comment: @coffeemath yes, you are right, i haven't phrased that part well, i meant equivalent... but why the fact that they are equivalent implies the equality he has written as a concenquence of 1 and 5?

Comment: @Ian, i agree, thank you for your explanation, but the thing that is bothering me is the way he got to the equality from (1) and (5)... i belive (if i am not hallucinating) that it doesn't necessarily implies the equality...

Comment: It's not from the statements (1) and (5) themselves (which are not universally true or false, it depends on the value of p/q which is not fixed). What's going on is "for fixed $a$, the statements $p/q < a$ and $p/q < \sqrt{\alpha S_a}$ have the same truth value for any rational number $p/q$ so $a=\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $\alpha S$ represents the area of $S$.

Now, your question is why do $(1)$ and $(5)$ imply $a=\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$. This is a very standard philosophy in mathematics. Think about it in this way-

You have shown that $\frac p q<a \iff \frac p q<\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$. But, the choice of $\frac p q$ was also arbitrary. So, the fact that $\frac p q<\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$ whenever $\frac p q<a$ holds **for all** $\frac p q<a$. Just ponder upon this for a moment and you'll realise that it can only be true if $a=\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$.

---

Once you are done pondering, here's a mathematical proof-

If possible let $a\neq\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$.

Without loss of generality, assume $a>\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$. Now, because of the way the rationals are distributed, given any $A$ and $B$, there is a rational number between $A$ and $B$. So, let $\frac x y$ be a rational number between $a$ and $\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$. So, $\frac x y<\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$ but $a>\frac x y$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $(1)$ and $(5)$ are equivalent.

Comment: I am not sure that I got what you are saying - you say that the only way for those statements to hold is if $a=\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$ since we can always find a $\frac x y$ such that it will be between $a$ and $\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$, but it is a contradiction to the fact that $\frac x y$ has to be smaller than a, so the only way to prevent that contradiction is if $a=\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$?

Comment: @RTabak Yes, that's precisely the mathematical part. But, since you said you're still confused, I would advise you to think geometrically instead of giving too much attention to the mathematical proof. Think of it in this way- picture $a>b$ (let's use $b$ for $\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$) on the number line, take a rational $r_1$ between $a$ and $b$, since $a$ has to be smaller than that, you have to drag $a$ to the left of of $r_1$, take another rational $r_2$ in between $b$ and the new $a$ and you need to drag $a$ again to the left. Continue this process to see that $a$ will eventually fall into $b$.

Comment: @RTabak Maybe I can write one more mathematical proof which will capture this geometry better. I was thinking about that version last night, but I was too lazy to write another proof down. Give me some time, I'll try my hands on that one as well.

Comment: @RTabak Check the other answer. Does it help?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @RTabak You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another mathematical proof of the given fact. This is not really radically different from the last one, but it's more geometric in the sense that it makes the picture much more clear.

We will use $b=\sqrt{\alpha S_a}$ in this argument.

If possible let $a\neq b$ and $|b-a|=d$.

Now, because of the structure of the reals, for any $r\in \mathbb R$, we can find a sequence of rationals $\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ which converges to $r$. So, take a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ which converges to $a$. Put $\epsilon=\frac d 2$. Because of convergence, for this choice of $\epsilon$, there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $|a-a_n|<\epsilon=\frac d 2$. This gives us a contradiction.

Another way to see it is to construct the sequence and argue that since we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n-a|=0$$
that is the distance between $a$ and a rational $a_n$ can be made arbitrarily small, $a$ and $b$ must coincide.

I hope this makes the geometry clear.